# How to protect a global variable shared by isr and regular function?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, mutex, semaphore

Let's say I have `function 1` and an `isr routine`, both share and update the same flag without any lock between them. **the system is single threaded.**

the while will be a 3 arm assembly instructions, which means it is not atomic operation, is it ok to share a global variable between non isr and isr functions without any lock or protection?

**function 1:**

```
while (flag == false);
flag = false;
```

**isr routine:**

```
do something
flag=true
```

---

I don't remember there is a linux kernel mechanism for locking between sleepable and non sleepable context e.g. `irq` and `kernel thread`.

---

**Thanks @artless for his answer here are some issues I am not sure about:**

1. Is there a way I won't miss interrupt at all ?
2. How the memory barriers solve the issue, does it have effect when the code runs on single cpu ?
3. What is the expected behavior when using barriers between different contexts ?
4. Can a sleep in the while `loop` can solve problems of syncs ?

Comment: Make sure that `flag` is declared `volatile`, otherwise the compiler is free to optimize `while (flag == false);` as `while (true);` since it will likely detect that `flag` cannot be changed from within function 1.  Marking it `volatile` informs the compiler that the variable is subject to change at any time.  (Since the system is single threaded, a memory barrier should not be required.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `volatile` is often quoted as a solution, but this is not quite true.  It will often mask a problem as `volatile` will always make code slower.  If your only use is as shown, then `volatile` will probably work.

It is probably better with a *single reader* and *single write* to use [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).  This would be your code then,

**Mainline:**

```
volatile int *p = &flag;
while (*p == false);   /* You must use volatile if you poll */
flag = false;
asm volatile ("" : : : "memory"); /* gcc barrier */
```

**isr:**

```
/* do something */
flag=true
asm volatile ("" : : : "memory"); /* gcc barrier */
```

Here, the *barrier* just forces the compiler to do the **ARM** `str` instruction at that point.  The optimizer will not move any code before or after.  You can also use `swp` or `ldrex` and `strex` depending on your **ARM** CPU.  As well, ring buffers are often used with *ISR* and *mainlines* as they don't need any special CPU support; only the compiler *memory barrier*.

See the [lock-free](/questions/tagged/lock-free) and specifically search [*lock-free* and *arm*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lock-free+arm).

**Edit:** For additions,

> Is there a way I won't miss interrupt at all ?

This is dependent on the interrupt source.  If it is a timer and you *know* the timer source can never be faster than **XX** instructions and no other interrupts are active in the system, then your current code will work.  However, if the interrupt is from an external source like an *Ethernet* controller, a non-debounced keypad, etc.  It is possible for multiple interrupts to come quickly.  Some times new interrupts even happen during the interrupt handler.  Depending on the ISR source, there are different solutions.  A *ring buffer* is commonly used to queue work items from the **ISR** for the main line.  For a **UART**, the ring might contain actual character data.  It could be a list of pointer, etc.  It is difficult to synchronize the **ISR** from the **mainline** when the communication becomes more complex; So I believe the answer depends on the interrupt source.  This is why every *OS* has so many primitives and infra-structure for this issue.

> How the memory barriers solve the issue, does it have effect when the code runs on single cpu ?

Memory barriers don't completely solve the missed interrupt issue; just like `volatile` doesn't.  They just make the *window* much smaller.  They force the compiler to *schedule* a load or store earlier.  For example the main line loop,

```
  1: ldr r0, [r1]
     cmp r0, #0    ; xxx
     bne 1b        ; xxx
     mov r0,#1     ; xxx
     str r0, [r1]
```

If a 2nd interrupt happens during the *xxx* lines, then your `flag` should be set twice and you missed one interrupt.  The *barriers* just make sure the compiler places the `ldr` and `str` close together.

> What is the expected behavior when using barriers between different contexts?

The compiler *memory barrier* I show just makes the compiler *do stuff* sooner.  It has no effect between contexts.  There are different *barriers*; but mostly they are for multi-CPU designs.

> Can a sleep in the while loop can solve problems of syncs?

Not really, this is just a more efficient use.  The ARM `WFI` instruction can temporarily *stop* the CPU and this will save power.  That is normally what *sleep()* does on the ARM.  I think you need to change the communication between the **ISR** and the **mainline**, if this is an issue.  That depends on the **ISR** source.

Comment: [Linux's memory barriers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) gives a good example of different types of issues you may encounter with synchronization.  Your current structure can always miss an interrupt, for instance.  Ie, between polling and resetting the flag to `false`, another interrupt may occur.

Comment: Updated my question, and found nice reference about arm and memory: http://engenuics.com/mpg/notes/notes_mpgl1_chapter6.pdf

Comment: thanks again for your awesome answers. So basically there is no 100% method I can use and won't miss any interrupt ? the interrupt source could be UART/USB, which is external, can you consult what mechanism can I consider for that?

Comment: There are 100% ways for different devices.  I don't think that this `flag` method is reliable for all devices.  You need to *service* the device in the ISR and then *queue* work to a mainline.  Your `flag` method works pretty well with a timer tick interrupt for instance.

Comment: Is volatile still needed if memory barriers are used and mainline only access the data with interrupts disabled?  This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26918909/1048959) but there was no solid answer.

Comment: Generally `volatile` is not needed/desired if you use a compiler memory barrier.  Whether it is **needed** or not is a question of how the variables are being used.  Mainline read/clear, interrupt set?  Or is there calculation going on?  Is the memory cached/non-cached?  Is it SMP?  If things seem to correct by adding volatile to a memory barrier, you probably just changed the timing and a race still exists.

Comment: It is more portable to use the C11 and C++11 atomic APIs. These will provide the necessary memory barriers without resorting to platform dependent code.

Comment: That is true for typical user space programming. It may not be true for functionally safe programming where only certain certified tools and libraries maybe used. So a good point, but not 100% universally true; especially in the context of system level driver code. I think standard atomics do very well for SMP synchronization, but often there are OS level nuances where they do not do as well for ISRs. Absolutely worth considering C11/C++ atomics.  Platform dependant code can be localized and well documented; so it should be balanced with other factors.  Answered in spirit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you can declare the flag as : `volatile int flag;` or `volatile bool flag;`

Answer (score 0):

This should help prevent missed interrupt. It is based on the wonderfully detailed ans from @artless_noise

Here the ISR posts on a semaphore(non blocking call). Adding the barrier to ensure that write completes.
The thread will run as many times as the semaphore is posted.

```
sem = sem_open(argv[optind], flags, perms, 0); // Initialising semaphore to 0

function 1:

while(sem_getvalue(sem) > 0)
{
   flag = false;
   //Avoiding the barrier if this value isnt needed by ISR
   asm volatile ("" : : : "memory"); /* gcc barrier */
   //perform action
}

isr routine:
    do something
    flag=true;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory"); /* gcc barrier */
    sem_post(sem);
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes.  If it is a single threaded model, there is no need for a lock.