# Attaching a method to an interrupt routine in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, arm, embedded, interrupt

I am writing a small framework for my embedded robotics project. We are running on a Xilinx Zynq FPGA (FPGA and ARM Cortex A9 embedded on a single chip)

The idea is relatively simple. In my `main()` I want to initialize the interrupt and then invoke the routine (a `run()` method) from the main as well. Somehow that `run()` method has to be attached to the interrupt while they are in separate locations in the code.

The interrupt is initialized in a static `Timer` class. Inside `initInterrupt()` the `interruptRoutine()` is attached which is also in the `Timer` class. Ultimately this forces us that all our code has to run **within** `interruptRoutine()`.

Somehow we want to have a `run()` method inside the `main.cc` file (above the `Timer` class) which stores all the logic and all other function calls.

How can we achieve this?

The main.cc:

```
int main() {
    Timer::initInterrupt();
    Timer::run([] {
        // All logic goes here?
        // Very hopeful thinking that this is possible...
    });
}
```

The timer class:

```
class Timer {
public:
    static void initInterrupt(void);
    static void interruptRoutine(void*);
    static void run();

};

    /**
     * Initialize main interrupt routine
     */
    void initInterrupt(void) {
    // Declare pointers
    XScuTimer_Config* ConfigPtr;
    XScuGic_Config* IntcConfig;

    // Initialize timers by looking up config and initializing with that config
    ConfigPtr = XScuTimer_LookupConfig(TIMER_DEVICE_ID);
    XScuTimer_CfgInitialize(&TimerInstance, ConfigPtr, ConfigPtr->BaseAddr);
    IntcConfig = XScuGic_LookupConfig(INTC_DEVICE_ID);
    XScuGic_CfgInitialize(&IntcInstance, IntcConfig,
            IntcConfig->CpuBaseAddress);

    // Initialize exception handling
    Xil_ExceptionInit();
    Xil_ExceptionRegisterHandler(XIL_EXCEPTION_ID_IRQ_INT,
            (Xil_ExceptionHandler) XScuGic_InterruptHandler, &IntcInstance);

    // Connect interrupt routine to exception handler
    XScuGic_Connect(&IntcInstance, TIMER_IRPT_INTR,
            (Xil_ExceptionHandler) interruptRoutine, (void *) (&TimerInstance));

    // Enable interrupts
    XScuGic_Enable(&IntcInstance, TIMER_IRPT_INTR);
    XScuTimer_EnableInterrupt(&TimerInstance);

    // Enable exception handler
    Xil_ExceptionEnable();

    // Set auto reload so timer reloads when interrupt is cleared
    XScuTimer_EnableAutoReload(&TimerInstance);

    // Set timer value
    XScuTimer_LoadTimer(&TimerInstance, TIMER_LOAD_VALUE);

    // Start interrupt
    XScuTimer_Start (&TimerInstance);
}
/**
 * main interrupt routine
 */
inline void Timer::interruptRoutine(void *CallBackRef) {
    // Define pointer to timer
    XScuTimer *TimerInstancePtr = (XScuTimer *) CallBackRef;

    // If timer is expired, clear interrupt status
    if (XScuTimer_IsExpired(TimerInstancePtr)) {
        XScuTimer_ClearInterruptStatus(TimerInstancePtr);

        // Currently all the application logic is handled in here
    }
}

inline void Timer::run(Callback){
    // We want all our application logic to be handled in here but it has to be called from the main()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the timer class, add a boolean flag "timer elapsed". This flag is set from the timer callback.

The main program then checks this flag through a getter function in the timer class.

If the flag is set, `main` clears the flag through a setter function in the timer class, and then executes the code that needs to be executed.

Please have in mind that access to the flag has to be atomic! Not an issue from inside the ISR, assuming it can't get interrupted, but it could be an issue inside the mentioned setter/getter functions.

Note that the above is perhaps the most common way to design interrupt. You will want to avoid executing the actual code from inside the ISR unless your real-time requirements are very tough.

Comment: Since we are sampling at about 20kHz our real time requirement is kinda tough.. But we will definitely give it a try. Could you perhaps show a bit of sample code on how to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you need some primitives to signal from the interrupt handler to the `Timer::run()` method.  The first issue is that you current code does not provide a `this` pointer for the timer interrupt.  You appear to be using the [xscutimer.h](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Xcell-Daily-Blog/Implementing-the-Zynq-SoC-s-Private-Timer-Adam-Taylor-s-MicroZed/ba-p/402203) code.  You have this code,

```
// Connect interrupt routine to exception handler
XScuGic_Connect(&IntcInstance, TIMER_IRPT_INTR,
        (Xil_ExceptionHandler) interruptRoutine, (void *) (&TimerInstance));
```

The `TimerInstance` value is unclear from your code snippet.  However, it should be a static `Timer` class instance.  Also `Timer::interruptRoutine` should be a `static` method and not `inline`. Then your `Timer` class should have a `XScuTimer` member.  Also, you need some sort of signalling to the run method and ideally a `yield()` type function.  Then the run would look like,

```
 Timer::run() {
    while(1) {
     while(no_work)
        wfi();  //ARM typically has a wfi or wait for interrupt.
     // do work
    }
 }
```

The `yield` ideally has a *wait for interrupt* instruction at it's core to minimize power consumption. You can just spin on `no_work` if you don't care about power consumption. Of course `no_work` must be set to `false` by the `Timer::interruptRoutine`.

The `no_work` variable should be lock free or interrupt safe.  `sig_atomic_t` or other means (depending on your work) are appropriate.  Either the tool kit has these things or you have to implement them yourself.  Please give a reference to the xilinx library that you are using.

This question on a [global variable and ISR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088873/how-to-protect-a-global-variable-shared-by-isr-and-regular-function) may be useful.  For you Cortex-A CPU, you can use `ldrex` and `strex` with all their caveats (not so easy to use as people think) for quite flexible ISR/mainline signalling.  Depending on your compiler/library it maybe provided by the [C++ lock-free/atomic](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/) functionality or something suitable in the Xilinx libraries; these can use `ldrex` and `strex` in the underlying implementation and you avoid having to know the complexity of using them.  The MMU must be in use for them to work.

Comment: I have updated my code. I was indeed missing a chunk of code in the `initInterrupt()` I will definitely take a look at what you suggested. However, it still seems that all the work is done inside the Timer class which is exactly what I am trying to avoid (readability and structure of code).

Comment: If you don't want the code in `Timer`, they you need to pass information to `initInterrupt()` or to the `Timer::run()` method.  You could just call it `Timer::waitToRun()`.  This puts the code in your `main()`... `while(Timer::waitToRun()) { /* main code */ }`. It looks like you want to pass around the code to execute.  I don't see what that gains except a lot of fancy C++ syntax that will probably only make things slower and certainly more complex for most people to grok?

Answer (score 0):

Either this is simpler than you think, or more complex than you've explained!

`Timer::run()` does stuff:-

```
inline void Timer::run()
{
... complex stuff...
}
```

Your interrupt routine calls `run()`

```
inline void Timer::interruptRoutine(void *CallBackRef) {
    // Define pointer to timer
    XScuTimer *TimerInstancePtr = (XScuTimer *) CallBackRef;

    // If timer is expired, clear interrupt status
    if (XScuTimer_IsExpired(TimerInstancePtr)) {
        XScuTimer_ClearInterruptStatus(TimerInstancePtr);

    run();
 }
```

And you want to call `run()` from main...

```
int main() {
    Timer::initInterrupt();
    Timer::run();
}
```

It's not clear if you want to avoid putting the `run` logic within the `Timer` class? If so, make `run()` be a abstract virtual method of a `Timer` instance, then derive `MyTimer` from `Timer`, and add youir code to it's `run()` method.

Comment: I think it's a bit more complexed than I explained. I don't want my `Timer` class to know anything about any logic. It follows SRP. The main delegates everything, but I somehow need to execute all that code on an interrupt. The problem is that the only place where I can do it for now is inside the `Timer` class in the `interruptRoutine()`

Comment: @Ortix92 - what about the virtual method in a derived class ans I mentioned? Would that work for you? Otherwise just use a regular callback function.