# Reading a value via an interrupt protection

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller

I am familiar with the race condition and the famous counter++ example.
My question is not about read-write protection, but only about read protection.
Is it possible I read a corrupt value via an interrupt? incase another interrupt/main code was just in the process of changing its value?
Do I need to protect my reads of let's say volatile components?
I am using C and an ARM microcontroller.

Furthermore, if only one task is doing read-write manipulation on some variable, and all other tasks are only reading it, do I need to protect it?

Comment: What reads what from where? The ISR reads a variable shared with background program, or...? I don't understand the question, please make a simple pseudo code example to illustrate.

Comment: Here's some info regarding use of volatile with ISRs, also addressing the separate problem of race conditions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102

Comment: There are specific arm documents on this.  For instance an aligned 32 bit is always ok.  However, 64 bits could take several bus cycles and be interrupted mid-cycle as a hypothetical;  consult your arm arm for real details.

Comment: A similar question and answers on [how to protect a global variable shared by isr and regular function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088873/how-to-protect-a-global-variable-shared-by-isr-and-regular-function).   [sig_atomic_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931456/how-does-sig-atomic-t-actually-work) is some what related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
do
{
   Read_Flag = 0;
   //Read operation
} while (Read_Flag);
```

Read_Flag  to be set at ISR where value of a variable being read is modified.